# Printing the contents of a file including ANSI colors from a Makefile

Tags: makefile, terminal, github-actions

I have a logfile in a Makefile that contains log lines including ANSI colored output. I want to echo the contents of this file to the terminal in a way that includes the color output. If I do

```
@cat $(LOGFILE)
```

it echos the output with colors on my machine, but on GitHub Actions, the ANSI colors are not shown. I know that ANSI colors can work on GitHub Actions, because something like `@printf "\033[0;31mThis is red\033[0m\n"` works just fine.

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262185/display-file-with-ansi-colors I think I need to do something like `echo -e $(cat filename)`, but I can't figure out how to translate that into Makefile syntax with the `$(LOGFILE)` variable.

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Have you tried `$(info $(file < $(LOGFILE))`? Maybe going via the `make` internal terminal write takes away any platform- or terminal-type dependencies?

Comment: @Vroomfondel I'm not sure I understand what `info` would do here. At any rate, the code you gave is evidently invalid Makefile syntax. Also my understanding is that the `<` syntax is only available on newer versions of GNU make, so I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Info is make's onboard cat command, if you will. The syntax is missing the closing ")" but otherwise correct  make for GNUmake >= 4 I think, which came out in 2013, so "new" is rather relative.

Comment: @Vroomfondel apparently the version of make that ships with macOS is still version 3, so it's still a little nonportable.

Comment: You could still try `logfilecontents := $(shell cat $(LOGFILE))`and then `$(info $(logfilecontents))`to circumvent the new syntax.